# Problem with spreadtab package: "Paragraph ended before \ST@left@ii was complete"

Tags: tables, spreadtab

I'm having issues with this table and can't find the problem. I'm including all the packages I'm using for customizing the table:

```
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{arydshln} % For the dotted line on the table
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Apply vertical padding to table cells
\usepackage{hhline} % For single-cell borders
\newcounter{pos}
\setcounter{pos}{0}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}[t t t]{lp{8.2cm}r}}
  \hdashline[1pt/1pt]
  \STtextcell \textbf{Pos.} & \STtextcell \textbf{Leistung/Beschreibung} & \STtextcell \textbf{Preise in EUR} \\ \hline
  \STtextcell \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & \STtextcell Die erste Leistung  & 750.0 \\
  \STtextcell \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & \STtextcell Die zweite Leistung & 180.0 \\
  \STtextcell \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & \STtextcell Die dritte Leistung & 55.0  \\
  \STtextcell \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & \STtextcell Die fierte Leistung & 55.0 \\ \hline
  \STtextcell & \STtextcell \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Rechnungsbetrag:}}   & \textbf{sum(c1:c4)} \\ \hhline{~~-}
\end{spreadtab}
```

I'm getting the following error: `Paragraph ended before \ST@left@ii was complete.` Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Replace `\STtextcell` by `@` and change `\textbf{sum(c1:c4)}` into `\textbf{:={sum(c1:c4)}}`

Comment: That worked, thanks. If you post your suggestion as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Anyway, I thought `@` and `\STtextcell` were equivalent, but it doesn't work using `\STtextcell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `\STtextcell` by `@`. By redefining `\STtextcell` you can change the marker for text cells but you can't use `\STtextcell` directly.

Also change `\textbf{sum(c1:c4)}` into `\textbf{:={sum(c2:c5)}}`. This is explained in the manual in the section about *mixed cells* where `\textbf` is actually shown as an example:

> Note that ‘`:={numeric field}`’ may be inside brackets, whatever be the
>   level of nesting. For example, if a cell contains `\textbf{:={a1+1}}`
>   and if the numeric value of the cell `a1` is `5`, then finally, the cell
>   will contain `\textbf{6}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{spreadtab,array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcounter{pos}

\begin{document}

\STautoround*{2}
\STsetdecimalsep{,}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}[t t t]{lp{8.2cm}r}}
  \hdashline[1pt/1pt]
  @ \textbf{Pos.} &
  @ \textbf{Leistung/Beschreibung} &
  @ \textbf{Preise in EUR} \\ \hline
  @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die erste Leistung   & 750.0 \\
  @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die zweite Leistung  & 180.0 \\
  @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die dritte Leistung  & 55.0  \\
  @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die vierte Leistung  & 55.0 \\
  \hline
  @ &
  @ \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Rechnungsbetrag:}} &
  \textbf{:={sum(c2:c5)}}
  \\ \hhline{~~-}
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The \hdashline gives me `! Paragraph ended before \ST@left@ii was complete.`. Without the \hdashline, the error is `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=20000].` I'm freaking out. Spending hours on a stupid table.