# Expand command in a spreadtab formula

Tags: tables, counters, pandoc, spreadtab

Long story short: I'm trying to come up with a system to generate a LaTeX table dynamically from a YAML file through Pandoc and do some calculations using the `spreadtab` package.

So far so good, the table gets output as it should and `spreadtab` does its job wonderfully.

I have a problem now, though. I need to find a way to tell `spreadtab` the range of cells whose values need to be summed. Since the table gets generated dynamically, this parameter needs to be dynamic as well. And since [there is](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2306) [no way](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/mNBoxUAto9w) with Pandoc to keep track of the number of iterations in a loop with a counter, I need to create said counter with LaTeX.

This is the solution I came up with (spoiler: it doesn't work):

```
\newcounter{pos}
\setcounter{pos}{0}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}[t t t]{lp{8.2cm}r}}
   @ Pos. & @ Leistung/Beschreibung & @ Preise in EUR \\ \hline
   @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die erste Leistung   & 750.0 \\ 
   @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die zweite Leistung  & 180.0 \\ 
   @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die dritte Leistung  & 55.0 \\ 
   @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die vierte Leistung  & 55.0 \\ 
   \hline
  @ & @ \multicolumn{1}{r}{Nettobetrag:} & :={sum(c1:c\thepos)} \\
\end{spreadtab}
```

The tricky bit is in the last line of the table. After incrementing the counter at every line, my plan was to use the same counter in the `spreadtab` formula to set the range of the cells that need to be summed. Unfortunately, `spreadtab` doesn't seem to expand the counter when it reads the table, and it returns the error: `Invalid range in cell C6`.

I thought this through and decided that a solution to this is beyond my powers. So now I'm asking you: How to use a dynamic parameter that `spreadtab` can recognize, or how to tell `spreadtab` to expand the counter command *before* executing the formula?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You know it would be easier to help you if you provided *complete* examples. You want `sum(c2:[0,-1])` instead of `sum(c1:c\thepos)`, see the `spreadtab` manual for relative references.

Comment: What do you mean with complete? Like, standalone documents you can copy-paste and compile on the fly? Anyway, that's brilliant and simple, I didn't think about relative references. Thanks again, @clemens!

Comment: By complete I mean that I can copy and paste it without having to add `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and any `\usepackage{...}`. In other words: I mean a minimal working example

Comment: Gotcha, will do in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose another solution: use relative referencing (as described in the `spreadtab` manual), i.e., use `sum(c2:[0,-1])` instead of `sum(c1:c\thepos)`. (Note I exchanged `c1` for `c2` – `c1` is the head of the column and the first number to be summed up to is in `c2`.)

Using the table from [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275854/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{spreadtab,array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcounter{pos}

\begin{document}

\STautoround*{2}
\STsetdecimalsep{,}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}[t t t]{lp{8.2cm}r}}
  \hdashline[1pt/1pt]
  @ \textbf{Pos.} &
  @ \textbf{Leistung/Beschreibung} &
  @ \textbf{Preise in EUR} \\ \hline
  @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die erste Leistung  & 750.0 \\
  @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die zweite Leistung & 180.0 \\
  @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die dritte Leistung & 55.0  \\
  @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Die vierte Leistung & 55.0 \\
  % @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Noch eine Leistung  & 12.0 \\
  @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Noch eine Leistung  & 56.3 \\
  % @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Noch eine Leistung  & 987.0 \\
  % @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Noch eine Leistung  & 45.0 \\
  % @ \refstepcounter{pos} \thepos & @ Noch eine Leistung  & 31.31 \\
  \hline
  @ &
  @ \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Rechnungsbetrag:}} &
  \textbf{:={sum(c2:[0,-1])}}
  \\ \hhline{~~-}
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly and it's way simpler and more robust than my approach. Also thanks for spotting the "fierte" typo ;)